# K.cast and tf.cast wont transform datatype

Tags: tensorflow, keras, types, casting, boolean

I am working with Keras Functional API

the line `nonNegActivity = K.cast(K.greater_equal(activity,0.05),tf.float32)` should transform my activity to `bool` and then to `float32`, yet an **TypeError** is raised, when calling fit, stating :

`TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'values' has DataType bool not in list of allowed values: float32, float64, int32, uint8, int16, int8, int64, bfloat16, uint16, float16, uint32, uint64`

*Whole Model:*

```
X = Input(shape=(self.Tx,self.kx,))
lstm_regr = LSTM(400,return_sequences=True,activation="tanh")(X)regr = Dense(self.ky)(lstm_regr)
lstm_activity = LSTM(400,return_sequences=True,activation="sigmoid")(X) activity = Dense(self.ky)(lstm_activity)
nonNegActivity = K.cast(K.greater_equal(activity,0.05),tf.float32)
multiplied = Multiply()([nonNegActivity,regr])
out = [multiplied,activity]
model = Model(inputs=X, outputs=out)
```

Comment: Do you get the same result if you put the cast and the greater_equal into a lambda layer?

Comment: this solved the problem